# Android - JobServiceCompat Application unable to handle onStopJob

Tags: android, service, android-jobscheduler

Im using [this library (JobSchedulerCompat)](https://github.com/evant/JobSchedulerCompat) to schedule some job, but I am having the same error in random occasions.
The Logcat looks like this:

```
08-21 15:56:30.232  11953-11953/com.mypackage.jobscheduleexample E/JobServiceCompat﹕ Application unable to handle onStopJob.
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: me.tatarka.support.internal.job.JobSchedulerService$JobServiceConnection@41905038
            at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:973)
            at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1671)
            at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:536)
            at me.tatarka.support.internal.job.JobSchedulerService.finishJob(JobSchedulerService.java:212)
            at me.tatarka.support.internal.job.JobSchedulerService.access$000(JobSchedulerService.java:29)
            at me.tatarka.support.internal.job.JobSchedulerService$JobServiceConnection$1.acknowledgeStopMessage(JobSchedulerService.java:143)
            at me.tatarka.support.job.JobService$JobHandler.ackStopMessage(JobService.java:158)
            at me.tatarka.support.job.JobService$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobService.java:111)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-21 15:56:30.232  11953-11953/com.mypackage.jobscheduleexample E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.mypackage.jobscheduleexample, PID: 11953
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: me.tatarka.support.internal.job.JobSchedulerService$JobServiceConnection@41905038
            at me.tatarka.support.job.JobService$JobHandler.handleMessage(JobService.java:114)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The service is registered on Manifest with *export* parameter as True.

OnStopJob method i only return false, nothing else. This happens when i try to cancel all jobs from Job Scheduler by doing:

```
mJobScheduler.cancelAll();
```

**Edit: Sorry but i don't know how to format the Logcat in Stackoverflow, if you know please edit my question.**.

Comment: Just format it as code.